# D3 updating data on box plot without removing previous SVG first

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm following the box plot on this page [Box Plot Link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502). In this example it reads in the box plot values from a data file. I'm trying to add a button that will read in new data from another data file and update the box plot.

Here's the code they use to first create the box plot.

```
    var svg = d3.select("#viz").selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("class", "box")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(chart.duration(1000));
```

and this to update the box plots every second

```
 setInterval(function() {
    svg.datum(randomize).call(chart.duration(1000));
  }, 2000);
```

When I click on the update button it calls my snippet here:

```
    var svg = d3.select("#viz").selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("class", "box")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(chart.duration(1000));
```

However this won't update my boxplot. If I want the box plot to change, I have to first remove the box plot SVG first

```
d3.selectAll('svg').remove();
```

But I'd like to have an transition rather than new box plots. Why do I have to remove the previous SVG first? Any help?

Comment: Your second and third snippets of code appear to be there for the same purpose. I don't quite see the connection between them -- just the second snippet should update the plot fine, why are you using additional code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made the following changes to the update of the data

```
        var svg = d3.select("#viz").selectAll("svg").data(data)

        svg.call(chart.duration(duration));

        svg.enter().append("svg")
        .attr("class", "box")
        .attr("id", function (d, i) {
            return "box_" + i;
        })
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", function (d, i) {
            return "g_" + i;
        })
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(chart.duration(duration))
        svg.exit().remove();
```

and there is actually some bugs with that box.js code that needs to be fixed which I found about here:

[D3 Datum Update Boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676779/d3-datum-update-boxplot)